# An integrable and periodic function f(x)

Tags: calculus

For a periodic function we have: $$\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{b}^{na}f(t)dt+\int_{na}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{b+a}^{(n+1)a}f(t)dt+\int_{an}^{b+a}f(t)dt = \int_{na}^{(n+1)a}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt.$$ , but I don't understand how we obtain $\int _{b+a}^{\left(n+1\right)a}\:f\left(t\right)\:dt=\int _b^{na}\:f\left(t\right)dt$ in our equality?

Comment: Is $a$ the length of one period?

Comment: yes, a is the length of one period

Comment: You add $a$ to both the lower and the upper limit. You start with $b$ and $na$ and end up with $b+a$ and $na+a=(n+1)a$.

Comment: and how we split that? can you show me ? how you split $\int _b^{na}\:f\left(t\right)dt$ to obtain $\int _{b+a}^{\left(n+1\right)a}\:f\left(t\right)\:dt$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it mean for a function to have a period $a$ ? Informally, it means that the function values gets repeated after an increment of $a$ in the $x-$value. (domain value). Notationally,

$$a\textrm{ is period of }f\iff f(x)=f(x+a)~\forall~x,x+a\in\textrm{Dom(f)}$$

That gives us $na=na+a=n(a+1)$ and $b=b+a$ since $na$ and $b$ are domain values ($x-$values) for $f$ and $a$ is the period.

So, the definite integral remains the same.

Here's a simple diagram:

[image]

Comment: $\int _b^{b+a}\:f\left(t\right)\:dt=\int _0^a\:f\left(t\right)dt$ is general case for a periodic functions?

Comment: @Lucas, I have added a diagram for better understanding.

Comment: Take the curve as $f$

Comment: @Lucas, didn't it help you?

Comment: I can't see diagram...don't show me

Comment: @Lucas, [here](http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/iF1Msyw.png)'s the direct link to the diagram.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is the length of one period, then $f(t)=f(t-a)$ and so on. Then

$\int_{b+a}^{na+a}f(t)dt=\int_{b+a}^{na+a}f(t-a)dt=\text{(take $u=t-a$)}=\int_{b}^{na}f(u)du$

Comment: f(t) is not equal with f(t+a) ? or not matter?

Comment: @Lucas Well, $f(t)=f(t+a)=f(t+2a)=f(t+3a)=...=f(t-a)=f(t-2a)=...$ It's all the same.

Comment: I don't know that... my teacher don't tell me about this, thank you !

Comment: $\int _b^{b+a}\:f\left(t\right)\:dt=\int _0^a\:f\left(t\right)dt$ is general case for a periodic functions?

Comment: @Lucas This would be true if the period is $b$. Translations not related to the period do not preserve the function and neither the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be a primitive of $f$. Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, one has

$  \frac{d}{db} \int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt=  \frac{d}{db} [F(b+a)-F(b)]=F^ \prime (b+a)-F^ \prime (b)=f(b+a)-f(b)=0.$

since $f$ is $a$-periodic. Then, the integral $\int_{b}^{b+a}f(t)dt$ is independent of $b$, so one can take $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you,but I want to understand something else, how we demonstrate that $\int _{b+a}^{\left(n+1\right)a}\:f\left(t\right)\:dt$ is equal with $\int _b^{na}\:f\left(t\right)dt$ ?

Comment: This is a simpler question: it suffices to perform the change of variable $u=t-a$ in your right hand integral, you will got the left one after using the fact that  $f$ is $a$-periodic, namely $f(t-a)=f(t)$.

Comment: I know that was a simple question, but is my first time after a long time when I comeback to "play math", I forgot some things.. :D